# No effect when setting endpoints.health.sensitive=false in spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my application.yml:

```
endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false
```

but when I request /health, I always got only:

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

Any idea to fetch more information?

Comment: Please add some more context.

Comment: For me with "security not turned on" just setting `endpoints.trace.sensitive: false` was enough...

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried accessing other endpoints ?

I think security is enabled for actuator endpoints, because of which full content is not accessible, to access full content you have to disable security for actuator or have to use basic authentication credentials to access it.

To disable security, add the following in your application.yml -

```
management:
   security:
           enabled: false
```

Answer (score 3):

In 'application.properties' add:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

If you need more information, check [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints) and of course, I suggest you read the contents ralted to it, to understand what's happening.

Hope it is helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints

```
health

Shows application health information (when the application is secure, a simple ‘status’ when accessed over an unauthenticated connection or full message details when authenticated).
```

Do you use any kind of authentication ?

NB: By default the sensitive is false so overriding health.sensitive is not useful.